# Is there any way to edit 'refresh' entry from desktop context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, context-menu

I have searched through all context menu entries in windows registry editor (in places like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`) but was not able to find anything linking to the 'refresh' entry. I have come to a conclusion that some entries are hard coded in the OS. My ultimate goal was to assign a keyboard shortcut for such a context entry (like 'Next Desktop Background').

Is there any way through which I can access those entries?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Solution for any windows version is good for me.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this but I know that things changed with Windows 11.  That is why I asked you to add the tags. :)  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Looks like it can solve the problem. Thanks